# Prove that if $g(t)\to b$ as $t\to\infty$, then $f(b) = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Proof**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and let $b$ be a positive constant. Suppose that $g(t)$ is a solution of $y' = f(y)$. Prove that if $g(t)\to b$ as $t\to\infty$, then $f(b) = 0$.

Comment: What about $f(y) = 1$ and $g(t) = t$?  I can't even guess what the actual problem is, assuming you just made an error copying it.

Comment: You wrote $g(t)\to\infty$ in the title, but $g(t)\to b$ in the post. Which one is it?

Comment: oh! correct condition is g(t) ->b @AlannRosas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that since $y'=f(y),$ we have that as $t\rightarrow \infty,$
$$g'(t)=f(g(t))\rightarrow f(b).$$

So all we need to show is that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} g'(t)=0.$ Intuitively speaking, this makes sense as the function settles down as $t$ increases. Let us try to prove this.

By defintion, $$g'(t)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}.$$

So, as $g$ is differentiable everywhere (as $f$ is continuous) we have that

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}g'(t)=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}$$ $$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}=0.$$

This proves our claim (we can switch limits here by the Moore-Osgood Theorem).